# cd command in IPython vs. Spyder

Tags: python, ipython, cd

I know that many of the working directory prompts that work in IPython also work in Spyder as long as they're prefaced by %.

For example, `pwd` and `ls` work in IPython, but to run the same commands in Spyder they need to be prefaced with a % such as: `%pwd` and `%ls`.

To change the directory in IPython, I can run the cd command like: `cd C:\Users\`... HOWEVER, this doesn't seem to work in Spyder, even when prefaced with a %. Any suggestions?

I know that `os.chdir ('C:\\Users\\')` works, just trying to understand why `%cd C:\Users\` doesn't...

Comment: You want the directory of Python interpreter or of your script?

Comment: What do you mean when you say `%ls` and `%pwd` work in *base Python*? You start python and then type in python console, like `>>> %ls`? That does not work!

Comment: The directory of my Python interpreter.  I.e. my "working directory".

Comment: sorry, it works in Spyder. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `%foo`, that command is run in a new shell instance running as its own process. When that shell exits, changes to its state (such as its working directory) are lost with it; they don't effect the parent Python process that spawned it.

This is the same as how running `sh -c 'cd /'` doesn't change your current working directory in shell. (Indeed, running a new process as `sh -c "$some_command"` is exactly how the standard-C library call `system(some_command)`, and its Python equivalent `os.system(some_command)` works).